# Accordions labels on New contact, Adv search and View contact are hidden

Tags: contact-view

Since CiviCRM upgraded to 5.71 the accordion labels are not displaying making our users difficult to use. All the extensions are on the latest version, do not see any error messages on the browser console. Any help really appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have [Shoreditch extension installed](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) on your website. There have been lots of changes happened recently in CiviCRM for accordions, the extension maintainer will need to fix the styling code.

Alternatively, you can use [The island theme](https://civicrm.org/extensions/island-theme) which is a forked version of [Shoreditch extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch) and is maintained actively. The accordion is fixed in the latest code which is yet to released but you could apply the patch to make it work of latest available version

```
wget https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/theisland/-/archive/2.3.1/theisland-2.3.1.zip

unzip theisland-2.3.1.zip

cd theisland-2.3.1/css

rm custom-civicrm.css

wget https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/theisland/-/raw/main/css/custom-civicrm.css
```

Comment: Same issue for me using Shoreditch on 5.71.1 on Drupal 10 today. Switching to The Island theme latest published version 2.3.1 fixed it.

Comment: which 'custom-civicrm.css' do you mean in `rm custom-civicrm.css`?

Comment: There is a recent fix for color which is not yet released. You can delete the under the extension /css/custom-civicrm.css and download it from the gitlab